# How to reset a variable after 3 seconds in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-handler

I am trying to create a `Service`. In this `Service` I ahve this variable:

```
String command="Go"
```

I want to design a function that does this:

> Within 3 seconds, the command will return value "Go"
>
> If the time is bigger than 3 seconds, the command will be reset to "".

My current solution is using a `Thread`. Do you think it is a safe and good solution?

```
public String command;

public String getValue(){
    command="GO";
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        command="";
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return command;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are doing it at `MainThread` the app will not response to user and it's the worst thing can happen! I suggest you to use `RXJava` and be aware of blocking UI Thread!

```
Observable.just(comment)
            .delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            /*for doing at background*/
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            /*for responsing at maint thread*/
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
                @Override
                public void call(String s) {
                    comment = "";
                    // and other stuffs you wand after resetting the val
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

A good approach(based on you having a thread already) would be this:

```
long elapsed = (System.nanoTime()-startTime)/1000000;
if(elapsed>3000) {

    //reset your variable

    //Allow this to repeat:
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
}
```

In order to initialize, do `startTime = System.nanoTime();` where you would initialize the activity.

Now this method has a big drawback: You have to use it with a thread. It cannot be used alone as a listener if you want it to update after 3 seconds and not after 3 seconds on a button press.

Using a thread is a good idea if you want something done repeatedly, but beware of background memory hogging. You may want to create an async thread

Comment: Thanks. Do you use thread in your code. I did not see any thread code in your code. I do not need to repeat so I think the line `startTime = System.nanoTime();` is not necessary. Besieds, the initial value of `long startTime=0`. Is it right?

Comment: startTime = System.nanoTime to initialize. Must be done before calling this. startTime is a long. Thread is just a runnable. You don't need to limit the speed here. Use any thread you would like. You have to use startTime = System.nanoTime() at the start if you want to do this repeatedly from the second the app starts.

Answer (score -1):

A better approach would be to use handlers and `postDelayed` instead of `Thread.sleep()`.

`postDelayed` puts the Runnable in the handler thread's message queue. The message queue is processed when control returns to the thread's Looper.

`Thread.sleep()` blocks the thread.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        //Do stuff every 3000 ms  
        handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
      }
    }, 1500);
```

Comment: I tried it and it returned the error. It looks requires a runUI thread. Note that I am in service

Comment: perfect solution for your task, just remove Toast and handler code(as it will cause iteration, retain it if you wajt iteration), and replace the code with variable reset

Comment: @user3051460 Did you replace the Toast with actual code?

Comment: Hi. It has error. Please tried with your code. I used your code before. The error is `java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`